# Object-following Virtual Buttons

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, vuforia

As shown in the picture, I want to be able to maintain this placement of virtual buttons wherever the ball moves.

This is what I've tried:

---

1.

The cue ball is a Rigidbody with Bounce Material, so it can bounce off the cushions. So in this case, I tried making the Virtual Buttons RigidBody Components and adding the same force to the buttons, but this didn't work because it wasn't able to detect the cushions and kept moving forward.

---

2.

I gave it a collider, it would bounce off the cushion before the ball and that would disrupt the formation around the ball.

---

3.

I tried to parent the Virtual Buttons under the Cue Ball and the Cue Ball under the Image Target, but this didn't help since it all centered within the ball and overlapped. I couldn't move it at all (I don't know why)

---

**Willing to put a Bounty on the answer.**

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual Butttons sometimes don't move above the Image Target, I really don't know why. But here's a work around.

Now consider your CueBall the parent. Throw in 8 Empty GameObjects as child Objects. Position these GameObjects in the position around the ball that you wish to maintain through the movement.

Now each virtual button is put as a child to these GameObjects respectively.

And now script movement of the ball. You should see it works perfectly. Make sure you have your X and Z rotation restriction. I guess since it's a Cue ball and its white, the rotation won't be much of a problem, unless you're scripting for Curve shots as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great idea. Just tried it out. And no, I don't intend to do any trickshots lol.

Answer (score 0):

A solution might be to create a script to attach to your ImageTarget, that has 9 public transforms, (your 8 planes and the cue ball) that would then look at the cue ball's x and z coords, and then would change the planes' x and z coords accordingly.

Comment: Yeah, but the movement of the cue ball will be using physics, I don't think the planes will be able to keep track of that using a script. Can it?

I just know it has something to do with parenting. But just not able to place my finger on it.

Comment: @RJJ You don't move the planes, you reassign their location values. You have the script scan the location of the ball, and then your reassign the values of the planes based on that.
To reassign the value of an object, just use: `transform.position = new Vector3(XCoord,YCoord,ZCoord);`